# hugo won't render single page layout, instead uses _default single layout

Tags: hugo

)

I'm trying to create my own theme for hugo.io. So far, everything works fine. My only problem is, that I can't get hugo to render the custom layouts for single section content.

For posts this works fine:

- The index.html gets called correctly
- The single.html inside the "layouts/posts" gets called correctly
- For tutorials, the list layout works correctly
- The permalinks for all files and lists work correctly

The problem:
* For tutorials, the single layout doesn't call the "layouts/tutorials/single.html" layout. Instead it uses "layouts/_default/single.html"

I tried the following:

- add type= "tutorial" preface setting to all tutorial .md files
- add layout= "tutorial" preface setting to all tutorial .md files
- add a "tutorial.html" file inside the "layouts/_default" folder (also tried naming it "tutorials.html)
- add a "tutorial.html" file inside the "layouts" folder (same as above)

sadly, none of this works

My setup of content:

```
content
|__ posts
   |__ new_post.md
|__ tutorials
   |__ new-tutorial.md
```

My setup of layouts (inside my theme folder):

```
layouts
|__ _default
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__ posts
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__ tutorials
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__index.html
```

My single tutorial content (new-tutorial.md):

```
+++
title = "My new Tutorial"
date: 2019-10-04T14:10:46+02:00
draft: false
type: tutorial
layout: tutorial
+++

# Custom Content Headline
```

There is no error message from hugo.
I expect hugo to open the page "http://localhost:1313/tutorials/new-tutorial/ with the layout that lies in the file "layouts/tutorials/single.html"

Comment: Lastly I tried to re-setup the whole project. After I created a new site/project and created a new theme and done the whole copy&paste of all content and theme files... everything works fine again. So I assume the problem doen't lie inside the discussed files?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm facing a similar issue and am looking for clues.

Comment: @JensZalzala - did you solve it? I have the same issue..

Answer (score 0):

You should not specify `type: tutorial` and `type:tutorial` in new-tutorial.md in your case.

Hugo will use layouts/tutorials/single.html by default for tutorial section, see https://gohugo.io/templates/lookup-order/#examples-layout-lookup-for-regular-pages

Final result for new-tutorial.md will look like

```
+++
title = "My new Tutorial"
date: 2019-10-04T14:10:46+02:00
draft: false
+++

# Custom Content Headline
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Sadly, creating the files' header after your pattern won't work for me ;( I think there is something else going on.

Comment: I noted issue with metadata inside '+++' section, it should be in TOML format in your case (see docs https://gohugo.io/content-management/front-matter/#front-matter-formats)
Try use
```
+++
title = "My new Tutorial"
date = 2019-10-04T14:10:46+02:00
draft = false
+++
```

Answer (score 0):

Already solved the issue, the problem is in the type definition. Hugo by default gives the elements inside the tutorials folder, the type tutorials, if you change it to tutorial, you must make a subfolder with the tutorial htmls, that are the new type.

```
layouts
|__ _default
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__ posts
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__ tutorials
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__ tutorial
   |__ list.html
   |__ single.html
|__index.html
```

like it says in the documentation
[image: https://gohugo.io/templates/views#which-template-will-be-rendered]
In case I am not making my self clear, you can read about it [here](https://gohugo.io/content-management/types/) and [here](https://gohugo.io/templates/views#which-template-will-be-rendered)